Does a Mastermind killed by a Vigormortis cause an extra day?
A Vigormortis kills its own minion, a Mastermind. The Vigormortis is executed and dies. The wiki says that minions only keep their ability as long as the Vigormortis is alive, so does the Mastermind see the moment of the Vigormortis' death and cause an extra day, or does it have no ability by the time its ability checks if it should trigger?

I emailed the Pandemonium Institute and asked them this question. Their response was:

This is one of those edge cases that can be actually be ruled either way, so just be consistent and make sure your players know how you're running it.


OK wow, I didn't know you could just contact them like that. I guess that makes it official.

Blood on the Clocktower does not handle simultaneous events in a way that is unambiguous in every case. The trend is that all relevant abilities will function before the game advances but some exceptions can exist.
Compare "case law" for abilities that function in similar ways or similar situations.

If a Lleech 'host' is executed when three players are alive, the game does not end immediately because only two players live; instead the Lleech also dies and only one player lives. Good wins because all Demons are dead (and not Evil). This requires both deaths to be simultaneous before the game ends.

If the last living Demon dies and Scarlet Woman's ability is active, the game does not end immediately with Good's victory; instead the player with Scarlet Woman's ability becomes a Demon and the game continues.


Thus, the Vigormortis is executed and dies, and the Mastermind ability functions: the game is extended for one more day, after which the game is lost by an executed player's team, or lost by Evil if no execution occurs (because all Demons are dead).
